# how to make working SMTP_validateEmail on live site using php

Tags: validation, email

Not working SMTP_validateEmail on live site using php
https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/

```
<?php

/**
 * Example 1
 * Validate a single Email via SMTP
 */


// include SMTP Email Validation Class

require_once('smtp_validateEmail.class.php');

// the email to validate

$email = $_POST['name'];
// an optional sender

$sender = $_POST['name'];
// instantiate the class

$SMTP_Validator = new SMTP_validateEmail();
// turn on debugging if you want to view the SMTP transaction

//$SMTP_Validator->debug = true;
// do the validation

$results = $SMTP_Validator->validate(array($email), $sender);


// send email?

if ($results[$email]) {
 echo 1; 
} else {
  echo 0; 
}

    enter code here

?>
```

i am  having problem on live site but it works fine in localhost.it shows the print_r($results) in the localhost but shows array(0) result in live.i also find $this->sock value in the class smtp_validateEmail.class function validate(email) value empty in live. how to solve this issue any help will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

That **"Add your web server ip address to var $nameservers = array(‘192.168.0.1’); and if your web server has Port number then update it here var $port = (Port number); Hope you will get the output by making this changes."** Only work if you are sending mail with that script but cant tell if that mail checked is good one or not... I have been testing the code, try all changes, but still cant check other mails outside my domain. I can only make it work on my local and webserver host. Still cant call other servers to check if other mails from outside my domain are valid. Working on it.

Complete downloads are here for others to test : https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/downloads/list

Comment: Update: Got it working, now I can check if outside domain is valid or not (so program dont send the mail). I dont think I will be able to check if receiver user account is valid nor exists, Im getting some bounced mails back stating that "user not found" on non hotmail accounts, and "unavailable" on hotmail, I havent figure it out how to check on smtp server if mailbox unavailable, so my program doesnt send the mail waisting time and effort.  Best regards to all. LC

Answer (score 0):

Add your web server ip address to `var $nameservers = array(‘192.168.0.1’);`
and if your web server has Port number then update it here `var $port = (Port number);`
Hope you will get the output by making this changes.